# SupportMapFragment runtime error and IntellijIDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-maps-v2

I'm developing an Android APP and I would like to put in some maps.
So, because of some well known IntellijIDEA bugs, I tried to follow some pieces of suggestions I've found here and there to make it work, but I'm still into trouble.

So: to import the libs I needed, I followed [this good piece of suggestion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96525), also referenced here in stackoverflow.

I then created my test activity and its test layout. Here they are:

```
package org.altervista.bertuz83.sgaget;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


public class Prova extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.prova);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { }

}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SupportMapFragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Here are my project and modules structure:

[image]

When I try to run this what I obtain is a

> at org.altervista.bertuz83.sgaget.Prova.onCreate(Prova.java:23)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
>           ... 11 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.SupportMapFragment

so.. what's wrong? I've really tried everything now. I think the project is both well imported and compiled, but something is missing to run it smoothly. Any piece of suggestion is more than welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaand I succeeded!

I placed a normal fragment in place of a "SupportMapFragment" which still remains in the name property of course:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

case solved.